# Excluding keywords with --exclude <tag> not working robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am not sure if this even possible but I have a test case which uses  a certain keyword. I don't want to comment it. So I added a tag (ignoring) to the keyword :
`robot --exclude ignoring  path/to/test`

I still see the keyword has been executed when consulting the log file.

Is it even possible to use `--exclude` with keywords that are not test cases?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you cannot exclude keywords, only test cases.
If you could exclude keywords, it could cause test cases to become instable.